# Find the orthogonal vector of $f(x, y) = x^2y+y^3$ at a given point

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

**Question:** Which given vector is perpendicular to the following curve at the point (1, 2).$$f(x, y) = x^2y+y^3 = 10$$

**My attempt:** By taking the partial derivatives of this function, I was able to find that the gradient of the function is $(4, 13)$. Since the dot product of two vectors are zero if they are orthogonal with each other, I concluded the answer to be $<-13, 4>$. This turned out to be incorrect, however.

From my perspective, I imagine the gradient function to be similar to a slope function but in 3D and that it contains information regarding the function's rate of change at a given point.
But I've also seen pictures online that the gradient function is perpendicular to the function itself, which is quite confusing for me since the slope function is never perpendicular to the original function.

I would be much appreciated if someone could explain this to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the gradient $\nabla(f)$ as the ratio of change in $f$’s value to the change in position on $x-y$ plane. Now imagine what happen if you walk along the curve $f=10$ i.e. $\Delta f=0$

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\Delta f\\
\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x, \Delta y \to 0}{\nabla(f)}\cdot(\Delta x \hat{i} +\Delta y \hat{j})
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $(-13,4)$ that you find is actually not the vector perpendicular to the curve but is actually a vector tangent to the curve at that point. The vector you are looking for is actually the one perpendicular to this one. Oh wait, is $\nabla(f)$ perpendicular to $(-13,4)$ ? :)